# How can I write a simple color formatting script for LibreOffice?

Tags: automation, libreoffice

1. Select a Range
2. Iterate rows of selection. For each iteration, if value of first column of selection equals *x*, make current row colored red, else make current row colored green?

Comment: https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Conditional_Formatting ? http://superuser.com/q/598871/84724 ?

Comment: What have you tried?  A good resource for LO Basic is at http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you are asking, but sounds to me like you could use conditional formatting for that. If needed, you could use an extra column where the formula would return True if the row would need to be red, False otherwise. Also the equation would need to know where the ranges are, so maybe an extra column for that.

So a not so genius halfworking example:

```
  A  B  C  D
1 q  0  0  0
2 i  1  2  0
3 i  0  2  1
4 d  0  2  0
```

https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Conditional_Formatting
B would hold 1 for range start, 0 otherwise.

```
C2: =IF(B2=1;ROW();B1)
D2: =IF(A2=OFFSET($B$1;0;D2-1);1;0)
```

And conditional formatting should apply red if D1 was 1.

[Conditional Formatting Help](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Conditional_Formatting)